# Remove the common keys from two Dictionary and adding the left overs to a new third Dictionary?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two dictionary dict1 and dict2.

I have removed the common keys and stored in otherEntry.

`var otherEntry = dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys);`

how should I add the data of "otherEntry" to a new Dictionary dict3?

Comment: Could you please provide sample input as real C# code and then the desired output?

Comment: What values will you assign to the keys in the third dictionary?

Comment: Your code only gets the keys from `dict1` that don't exist in `dict2`, but what about the keys that exist in `dict2` but not `dict1`? Is the title of your question misleading or is your code wrong?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding of the requirements

> Take all the uncommon items between the two dictionaries and place them into a new dictionary

Consider the following

```
var dict3 = dict1.Concat(dict2)
    .GroupBy(_ => _.Key)
    .Where(_ => _.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(_ => _)
    .ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.Value);
```

Grouping the two collections by key and taking only the single item groups as this would exclude the items that exists in both collections and leave the rest left over.

From there it is just a matter of creating the dictionary from the remaining items.

Answer (score 3):

I would say

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict1.Add("abc", "hello");
dict1.Add("def", "world");

Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict2.Add("hij", "bonjour");
dict2.Add("abc", "le monde");


 Dictionary<string, string> dict3 = dict1
 .Where(kvp => !dict2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
 .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: This doesn't get keys that are in `dict2` but not `dict1`. Question title makes it sound like they want those.

Comment: @itsme86 Mmm yes I'm getting a bit puzzled now. I just completed the code but the title seems to express a different requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to join `otherEntry` with `dict1`. The `Join` operator will return an IEnumerable which you will need to convert to a Dictionary using the `ToDictionary` method since you want a Dictionary as the result.

```
dict1
    .Join(otherEntry, d1 => d1.Key, other => other, (d1, other) => d1)
    .ToDictionary(d1 => d1.Key, d1 => d1.Value);
```

Alternatively, you could achieve the same result using the LINQ equivalent of a left outer join

```
var otherEntry = 
        from d1 in dict1
        join d2 in dict2 on d1.Key equals d2.Key into matchingGroup
        where !matchingGroup.Any()
        select d1;

var dict3 = otherEntry.ToDictionary(d3 => d3.Key, d3 => d3.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via cycle `foreach` for example

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in dict1) {
  otherEntry.Add(item);
  if (dict2.ContainsKey(item.Key)) {
    dict2.Remove(item.Key);
  }
}
```

and then

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in dict2) {
  otherEntry.Add(item);
}
```